# binary tree level wise print function not working

Tags: c++, class, tree, queue, binary-tree

i need to create a function that prints level wise binary tree with its children for eg input is 1 in root its 2 children left is 10 , right is 12
then output will be like - 1:L:10,R:12 (then endl)  2:L:-1,R:-1 (then endl)  3:L:-1,R:-1 and so on level wise i do not know why my code is running infinite times thus giving time limit exceed error
if anyone could take a look

```
    #include<queue>
void printLevelWise(BinaryTreeNode<int> *root) {
if(root==NULL) return;
queue<BinaryTreeNode<int>*>q;
q.push(root);
while(q.size()!=0){
BinaryTreeNode<int> *front=q.front();
cout<<front->data<<":";
q.pop();

if(root->left!=NULL) {
    cout<<"L:"<<root->left->data;
    q.push(root->left);
}
else{
cout<<"L:-1";  
}

if(root->right!=NULL){
    cout<<",R:"<<root->right->data; 
    q.push(root->right);
     }
else{
cout<<",R:-1";  
}

cout<<endl;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you change your root in the iteration?
You should go down the root every time you check a node.
If not- why should the size would ever be 0?
You can do it in a recursive way. Thats might be the best solution for you.

Comment: How OP ever made sense of that (and even accepted it as an answer) will forever remain a mystery to me.

Comment: He is keep checking the same things in the if statements. I agree I didn't write it with too much information but apparently it have to do with the fact that if you keep checking the same thing and add the size of q by 1. you will get an infinite loop (let say that the root have 1 node in his left you will always get true) - maybe it will solve the mystrey thing of yours(:

Comment: after poping the element i should have replaced root to front in all the next lines which i did not , hence got my answer